# Resource allocation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

- I have a set of J jobs that need to be completed.
- All jobs take different times to complete, but the time is known.
- I have a set of R resources.
- Each recourse R may have any number from 1 to 100 instances.
- A Job may need to use any number of resources R.
- A job may need to use multiple instances of a resource R but never more than the resource R has instances (if a resource only has 2 instances, a job will never need more than 2 instances).
- Once a job completes it returns all instances of all resources it used back into the pool for other jobs to use.
- A job cannot be preempted once started.
- As long as resources allow, there is no limit to the number of jobs that can simultaneously execute.
- This is not a directed graph problem, the jobs J may execute in any order as long as they can claim their resources.

My Goal:
The optimal way to schedule the jobs to minimize run time and/or maximize resource utilization.

Comment: You would have to define what you mean by "best" way to compete all jobs, but this would still be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjABahUKEwjHqr-IqJrIAhXCFh4KHVRCB64&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.93.9807%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNGIlkzutTU2C-JYRG89HJWyvsCBeg a hybrid metaheuristic for the resource-constrained project scheduling problem

Comment: Sounds like [this resource optimization problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6KsveB6v-g) of the ICON challenge. Metaheuristics worked well on it. The open source implementation you see in that video won 2th prize.

Comment: Just got back to work for the day, making progress on the solution that you posted harold, will hopefully have more in a few hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how good this idea is, but you could model this as an integer linear program, as follows (not tested)

Define some constants,

```
Use[j,i] = amount of resource i used by job j
Time[j] = length of job j
Capacity[i] = amount of resource i available
```

Define some variables,

```
x[j,t] = job j starts at time t
r[i,t] = amount of resource of type i used at time t
slot[t] = is time slot t used
```

The constraints are,

```
// every job must start exactly once
(1). for every j, sum[t](x[j,t]) = 1
// a resource can only be used up to its capacity
(2). r[i,t] <= Capacity[i]
// if a job is running, it uses resources
(3). r[i,t] = sum[j | s <= t && s + Time[j] >= t] (x[j,s] * Use[j,i])
// if a job is running, then the time slot is used
(4). slot[t] >= x[j,s] iff s <= t && s + Time[j] >= t
```

The third constraint means that if a job was started recently enough that it's still running, then its resource usage is added to the currently used resources. The fourth constraint means that if a job was started recently enough that it's still running, then this time slot is used.

The objective function is the weighted sum of slots, with higher weights for later slots, so that it prefers to fill the early slots. In theory the weights must increase exponentially to ensure using a later time slot is always worse than any configuration that uses only earlier time slots, but solvers don't like that and in practice you can probably get away with using slower growing weights.

You will need enough slots such that a solution exists, but preferably not too many more than you end up needing, so I suggest you start with a greedy solution to give you a hopefully non-trivial upper bound on the number of time slots (obviously there is also the sum of the lengths of all tasks).

There are many ways to get a greedy solution, for example just schedule the jobs one by one in the earliest time slot it will go. It may work better to order them by some measure of "hardness" and put the hard ones in first, for example you could give them a score based on how badly they use a resource up (say, the sum of `Use[j,i] / Capacity[i]`, or maybe the maximum? who knows, try some things) and then order by that score in decreasing order.

As a bonus, you may not always have to solve the full ILP problem (which is NP-hard, so sometimes it can take a while), if you solve just the linear relaxation (allowing the variables to take fractional values, not just 0 or 1) you get a lower bound, and the approximate greedy solutions give upper bounds. If they are sufficiently close, you can skip the costly integer phase and take a greedy solution. In some cases this can even prove the greedy solution optimal, if the rounded-up objective from the linear relaxation is the same as the objective of the greedy solution.

Comment: I got a working version of the ILP implementation and it is accurate but  prohibitively slow on larger datasets. I am on to attempting the linear relaxation, but I am having trouble seeing how i could apply linear relaxation to the problem.

Comment: @Kaiser well, the relaxation is probably bad now that I think about it. Maybe I can improve the model, have some thinking to do for that

Comment: @Kaiser what is the linear relaxation actually doing by the way? And can I borrow one of your datasets?

Comment: I was not actually able to get the linear relaxation to do anything because i am having trouble seeing how to even apply a linear relaxation to the problem, and unfortunately i don't seem to be able to give you a real dataset so i will attempt to generate a fake one.

Comment: @Kaiser you can get the relaxation by not telling the solver that the variables are boolean, or there can be other ways, it depends on the solver. The solver does the relaxation anyway, it uses it as a guide to find the integer solution.

Comment: Could somebody tell what vertical bar in `sum[j | s <= t && s + Time[j] >= t]` means and why we multiply `(x[j,s] * Use[j,i])`.

Comment: @alanextar I used the vertical bar to denote that not *all* possible `j` are used, only those that satisfy the condition after the vertical bar. `Use[j,i]` is multiplied by `x[j,s]` there because `r[i,t]` is meant to count only how much resource is being used *at that moment*, so it must take into account which tasks are active at that moment (that's also why that complex condition is after the verticle bar) and how much resource each active task uses.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a job for [Dykstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).  For your case, if you want to maximize resource utilization, then each node in the search space is the result of adding a job to the list of jobs you'll do at once.  The edges will then be the resources which are left when you add a job to the list of jobs you'll do.

The goal then, is to find the path to the node which has an incoming edge which is the smallest value.

An alternative, which is more straight forward, is to view this as a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

To construct this problem as an instance of The Knapsack Problem, I'd do the following:

Assuming I have `J` jobs, `j_1, j_2, ..., j_n` and `R` resources, I want to find the subset of `J` such that when that subset is scheduled, `R` is minimized (I'll call that `J'`).

in pseudo-code:

```
def knapsack(J, R, J`):
  potential_solutions = []
  for j in J:
    if R > resources_used_by(j):
      potential_solutions.push( knapsack(J - j, R - resources_used_by(j), J' + j) )
    else:
      return J', R
  return best_solution_of(potential_solutions)
```

Comment: @Davidann , Interesting answer but I am having trouble seeing how this gives an optimal answer given that the jobs may take different time.  It seems the knapsack code is not accounting for jobs that may take several resources and run a long time and may group them with a job that may not take very long.   Your take on this?

Comment: @Kaiser: your goal was stated that you wanted to "minimize runtime and/or maximize resource utilization".  I opted for resource utilization.

Comment: @Davidann, Sorry i was not clear I am wondering how this takes into account that the jobs have different run times from one another.  Even if you are optimizing on resource utilization it seems like this knapsack variation has the assumption of even run time. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Kaiser: I don't think this algorithm takes into account how long it takes each job to run.  It only focuses on maximizing resource utilization.