# Resource with schedules allocation problem

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I have a [similar task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828059/resource-allocation-algorithm) but with differences in bold:

- I have a set of J jobs that need to be completed. Jobs are organized into set of directed graphs. Each job can have one or more preceding (parent) jobs that have to be completed before it starts.
- All jobs take different times to complete, but the time is known.
- I have a set of R human resources. **Each resource has a schedule** when it is available.
- Some jobs **can be preempted** once started. E.g. if a resource is not available at some specific hours then it can process the job after.
- A job may have a **predefined amount of resources which can be changed**. If algorithm can't find desired decision (all jobs couldn't be finished at some known date) then I can increase/decrease resource amount. The duration of a job changes proportionally with amount. E.g. J1 requires 1 human resource initially and estimated duration 1 hour. If I set 2 human resource then duration decreases to 0.5 hour.
- Resources have parameters that match tasks. E.g. If J1 has constraints {A,B} then we can assign resource R1 with permissions {A,B} which satisfied these constraints. If there is no appropriate resource then I can assign any of available.

**My goal:** Assign as much appropriate resources as possible so the job would finish at the time. How to solve this via simplex method? How equations would look like? What will be a complexity? I can't get close without brute force permutation.

I tried a greedy algorithm:

- I scheduled tasks from job start date without resource calendars considering only relations between tasks (I calculated order for each task in chain, where order 0 is the earliest predecessor). E.g. in chain J1 -> J2 -> J3, J3 must be done after finishing J1 and J2. J1.Order = 0, J2.Order = 1, J3.Order = 3.
- Then I sorted tasks by order and operations count. First goes the task with higher count of children. Then I sorted by count of required resources. And finally by initial duration.
- For each order I take a task and assign resources with satisfied skills and can do the task, then earlier, then better considering their calendars and business into another job.

This doesn't take into account predefined job finish date. It's far from optimal and another approach is needed. The greedy algorithm with a proof of correctness would also be acceptable.

Comment: What programming language? What have you done so far? What part don't you understand and need help with? Can you show us your code?

Comment: I don't think a pure linear-program will do the job. You will most likely need some kind of integrality.
Is there a reasonable way for you to discretize time? This would make some of the constraints easier to formulate. But it might also make your runtime explode.